# Read the web.config value from the aspx page in Classic ASP site

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have an asp site. I have some aspx also and put those pages into the asp site. Now I am able to access those pages through the asp site. However, there are some pages those are fetching the connection string or some AppSetting key-values from the web.config value.

```
connectionString = 
  Convert.ToString(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnString"]);
```

But as soon as I access those pages it shows the error

```
The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.
```

I have put the following code in the home.aspx page and called the page in the browser. But it does not show any value.

```
<% Response.Write(Convert.ToString(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnString"]);) %>
```

Please let me know how to access the web.config file values through the aspx page those are inside of the asp site. The web.config file and those pages are on the same root folder. Is there any setting in the IIS?

Comment: means you did something like this `SqlConnection conStr = new SqlConnection("");`

Comment: What are you asking? You want to read the `web.config` from the ASP.Net application but it's hosted inside a Classic ASP app is that right?

Comment: There are some asp.net pages in the Classic ASP app.

Comment: What line does the error occur on can you show the code for that line? At present you haven't provided enough information to reproduce this and your question will likely be closed or voted down.

Comment: Classic ASP and ASP.net pages can exist on the same site, they shouldn't interfere with each other.  Your aspx pages should be able to read web.config as if the Classic ASP pages weren't there

Comment: Fact is @John they need to show more code so we can stop trying to guess the problem, I'd suggest it's nothing to do with reading the web.config file but the OP failing to instantiate the `SQLConnection` properly. I also don't see why it's tagged [tag:asp-classic] as it's not relevant.

Comment: I am using the following code to print the connection string values in the aspx page, but does not return any value.   <% Response.Write(Convert.ToString(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnString"]);) %>

Comment: Is there any setting in the IIS?